# Printer selected is not valid and Catastrophic Failure in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, printers

My application is using delphi dlls for report purpose, it is plugged in main program to fetch reports. It raises exception for printers at the time of debugging, It does not comes always but it is very frequent it stops me going further for debugging, while exe does not raises any such error. These errors are coming at `OleCtnrs.pas` `CreateObjectFromInfo` while attempting to call `OleCheck` in case of `ctNewObject`, The errors are :

```
1. Project xyz.exe raised exception class EPrinter with message 'Printer selected is not valid'. Process stopped. User Step or Run to continue.
```

---

```
2. Access violation at address 0ADD4102 in module 'abcReport.dll'. Read of address 0fFD4018.
```

---

```
And finally : 
3. Project xyz.exe raised exception class EOleSysError with message 'Catastrophic failure'. Process stopped. User Step or Run to continue.
```

All this is very much confusing, from where to start and how to proceed. Can anybody suggest a possible workaround.

Comment: Start by making sure a default printer is assigned (in Devices and Printers). Old versions of Delphi had issues with using TPrinter when no default was assigned.

Comment: I think you need to do some debugging. Isolate where the exceptions are raised, and then decide how to deal with the issue. It's premature to ask for a workaround before you have actually identified the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Thanks David, I did alot debugging and searched for related forums but no clue it seems.

Comment: We cannot see the fruits of your debugging. We cannot see where your code raises these exceptions.

Comment: @KenWhite - Thanks Ken, I have tried that with a default printer and default pdf printer as well. As far as I can understand this is some machine configuration issue because these errors are coming at one machine only. Also I searched http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article//permalink.art-ng1612q9464 to be changed in printers.pas for printer issue.

Comment: I doubt you'll get very far with this trial and error guesswork based approach. Won't you find out what raises the exceptions? Wouldn't it be so much easier to solve the problem if you knew what the problem was? Do you need help in doing that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Hello David, I did further R&D and catch exact issue for printer problem. Actually my printers.pas raises exception at the time of debugging at this line of code - `DC := CreateHandleFunc(PChar(Driver), PChar(Device), nil, DevMode);` even after changing the code referring to the link http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article//permalink.art-ng1612q9464. I found same change where ever people are facing this issue. But it seems it is not helping me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes I need help in that.

Comment: I don't think I can help you with the details of this. It's good that you've tracked down the cause. But I guess you need more debugging to either be able to fix the problem, or avoid it.

Comment: If I can add a pointer here, does the printers that are causing the failure have a long name (like more than 16 or 32 chars) ? If I remember correctly, there was a limitation in the printer code of Delphi 7 that the printer name was in a array and a too long name caused the Printer not found problem. Was happening more with network printer since theirs name was very long.

Comment: @JFPicard - I am accessing this machine remotely but it accesses printer of my machine and no. of characters in name of default printer is 15 including spaces.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I am getting this issue now on `ctNewObject:
          OleCheck(OleCreate(ClassID, IOleObject, OLERENDER_DRAW, nil,Self, FStorage, FOleObject));` OleCtnrs.pas.  Delphi debugger is raising error exactly at this line of code where `OleCreate()` is not supporting. Detailed description mentioned at - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2708c1e-0d64-44b2-883c-f01076b0e44a/printer-selected-is-not-valid?forum=exceldev